# Facebook Apps: App is set as 810px wide in app options, but on the page itself it's still 520px

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-timeline

I'm having a wierd bug with Facebook right now.

Having installed Timeline on my FanPage, I went ahead and tried to make my apps in the new 810px-wide format.[image]

Thing is, after I saved that and went to my App to see the results, the app space is still 520px, taking barely half the space available.

I then took the Web Developper tools to find what exactly was blocking me at 520px; I found a div with the class profile-platform-pane and this has the css attributes width:520px and overflow:hidden. Switching it to 810px from the web master tools works. Thing is, this doesn't switch the attribute forever. Just refresh the page and its gone.

Now, what am I doing wrong to make Facebook not give me 810px wide of space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm having the same issue, but i think the root of my problem is with the app's use of FBML.

if you go to the advanced settings in developers.facebook there's an option for **Page Tab iframe** -- make sure that's enabled.